# What does Docker Quickstart Terminal do?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I just recently started using Docker. I'm able to run my servers, and communicate between them.

What I don't understand is: why do I need to run Docker commands, like `$ docker run somerepo/image` from the window opened by Docker Quickstart Terminal.

Running it from "regular" Terminal windows returns

```
$ docker run dockerinaction/hello_world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?. See 'docker run --help'.
```

I understand that on OS X and Windows, Docker needs to start one virtual machine with Linux 2.6 (in my case), and that all containers are run within that VM.

I thought docker CLI was connecting to a docker deamon that runs inside that VM - and then I don't understand what happens in the Quickstart Terminal.

Comment: my guess is that the terminal just setups environment variables and paths needed to run docker. If you look, you can probably find the init script and just source it inside your current terminal to make everything work.

Comment: Maybe  because your user not in the docker group? You can find it out by typing `groups` in regular terminal. More info can be found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand what does happen in the Quickstart Terminal.

You can use a regular terminal, provided by [`docker-machine env`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/), and do operations similar to [`osx/mpkg/quickstart.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh`](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/e24e33ea2f3f2c655fc4d07a671bd5f31ddfd95f/osx/mpkg/quickstart.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh#L42-L51):

```
dockerm-machine start dev
eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"
```

(replace '`dev`' with the name of your docker machine. By default, it is named... "`default`")

Once those environment variables for the Docker client are set, you can execute docker command directly from your shell.
A Quickstart Terminal would set those same variable for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can see what it does by watching the terminal output. In my case it ran *bash --login '/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh'* attempting to start the virtual machine. Once it's running it uses the equivalent of *﻿﻿eval "$(docker-machine env default)"* to set some environment variables so your terminal is ready to access the Docker VM.

If you need more information have a look at that script start.sh.

Answer (score 0):

**What does docker quickstart terminal do?**

From [Docker docs](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-toolbox-compose/#:%7E:text=Open%20Docker%20Quickstart%20Terminal.,whale%20and%20a%20command%20prompt.):

> It will create and start a VirtualBox VM running Docker Engine, then
> configure the command-line environment so that you can talk to it

In other words it sets some environment variables so your terminal is ready to access the Docker VM. - (thanks to @Nauraushaun)